# Python - Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: python

Я только начал изучать Python и первое задание было написать программу для сложения матриц NxM. Написал код, однако выдает ошибку:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\andrey\Desktop\Python\main.py", line 12, in <module>
>     C[i][j] = A[i][j]+B[i][j]
> IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

Пробовал изменять индексы, ничего так и не получил

```py
n, m = int(input()), int(input())
A = []
for i in range(n):
   A.append([input() for j in range(m)])

B = []
for i in range(n):
   B.append([input() for j in range(m)])

C = []
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
       C[i][j] = A[i][j]+B[i][j]
print(C)
```

Comment: `C[i]` — вы пытаетесь присваивать что-то в пустой список, что автоматически приводит к выходу за границы и возникновению этой ошибки

Comment: Вот тут вы создаете пустой список: `C = []`. А вот тут `C[i][j] = ` обращаетесь к элементам пустого списка как если бы список был списком списков (матрицей) :)

Comment: Спасибо, а можно как то решить, не задавая такой же список C[MxN] например из 0, тоже циклом, чтобы выглядело как костыль? Не нашел понятного объяснения в интернете, как это сделать

Answer (score 0):

Все базовые ошибки нужно знать!

Ваша ошибка `IndexError: list index out of range` в переводе означает `ошибка исчисления списка - требуемый элемент вне списка`.

Ошибка решается элементарным дебагом,- перед строкой ошибки вызываем принт (модуль `icecream`) вида

```
print(A,i, A[i],j,A[i][j]...) #то есть вывод всех переменных и их производных
C[i][j] = A[i][j]+B[i][j]
```

Здесь мы вычислим непосредственную ошибку, то есть может быть, что `i` больше длины списка, либо `j` больше длины списка. Но это элементарная ошибка, её дебаг банален, причина возникновения - незнание документации, либо незнание математики. Ваша вопрос звучит как "сделайте за меня".